# Too Many open file exception while indexin using solr

Tags: java, jboss, solr

I am using SOLR for indexing documents in my web application and solr.war is deployed on the jboss server.
But while indexing i am getting too many files open exception. Below is some of exceptions stack trace:

```
12:31:33,267 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "Lucene Merge Thread #0"
12:31:33,267 ERROR [STDERR] org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/jbossesb/bin/solr/data/index/_2rw.prx (Too many open files)
12:31:33,267 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:351)
12:31:33,267 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:315)
12:31:33,267 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/jbossesb/bin/solr/data/index/_2rw.prx (Too many open files)
12:31:33,267 ERROR [STDERR] at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File Descriptor](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/File_descriptors.html) will be your most likely cause.

Check the limit which your operating system has set. and adjust accordingliy.
on Unix, the command to view and set is [ulimit](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/man/man1/ulimit.html).

Comment: Hi, can you explain us how you can set this max value with ulimit for a specified user?

I search on a couple of sites but I didn't find the good command :(

Comment: **/etc/security/limits.conf** --- best place to set user based ulimit

Answer (score 5):

As explained in this [SOLR Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4), you can try the following options:

- increasing your ulimit using: `ulimit -n 1000000`
- set `useCompoundFile` to true in `solrconfig.xml` to use Lucene's compound file format
- use a lower `mergeFactor` which will result in fewer segments and hence fewer open files.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize the index. It probably has too many segments.

Answer (score 0):

Also try reducing the merge factor