# Apache solr getting (Too many open files)

Tags: java, apache, solr

We are using Apache Solr in production environment and we are getting following exception every week.

```
ERROR - 2015-06-19 00:45:02.127; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/solr/solr/list_activity_10_1847/data/index/_9_Lucene41_0.doc (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:389)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:282)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.unCache(NRTCachingDirectory.java:247)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.sync(NRTCachingDirectory.java:182)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4519)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2994)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3097)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3064)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:582)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:64)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1707)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1684)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:157)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerUtils.handleCommit(RequestHandlerUtils.java:69)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:78)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1967)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
```

After remove unwanted core and restart Solr this issue resolved temporary. I am unable to identify the root cause and looking some help for the permanent solution of the issue.

Comment: Not really sure but i have seen this error mostly on linux (not related to solr though). I had to increase the limit in /etc/security/limits.conf and got rid of it.

Comment: psiible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828343/too-many-open-file-exception-while-indexin-using-solr

Comment: On CentOS at least, the default limit of open files is a very conservative 1024, which is too small for many Solr installations. Follow the link that Abhijit gave to change that.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are running out of file descriptors. Run ulimit -n to see the current account limit per process.

On any lucene based search engine it is recommended to increase the limit. Follow your OSes instructions to permanently increase file descriptors available to a process. See some additional info here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/